# connection of deno to mongodb fails

Tags: mongodb, deno

I'm trying to connect my deno application to mongodb but I get error.

```
import {MongoClient} from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.21.2/mod.ts";

const client = await new MongoClient();
await client.connect("mongodb+srv://deno:i4vY8AtCEhr6ReqB@sample.7jp1l.mongodb.net/deno?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

const db = client.database("notes");

export default db;
```

everything seem to be fine but when I run the app, I get this error.

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: MongoError: "Connection failed: failed to lookup address information: nodename nor servname provided, or not known"
                throw new MongoError(`Connection failed: ${e.message || e}`);
              ^
    at MongoClient.connect (client.ts:93:15)
    at async mongodb.ts:4:1
```

Comment: Double check the <username> and <password>.

Comment: *failed to lookup address information:* - I don't think it's a problem with your code or Deno, but just an unreachable address. Try with a local db.

Comment: Have the same issue

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: looks like problem with URL.

Answer (score 5):

2 problems that I see:

- The code snippet above only works with Mongo installed in local machine.
- The connection string use DNS Seed List, but the current library couldn't resolve to a list of hosts

To make it works with Mongo Atlas, you need to call a **connect** method with difference parameters and find a correct (static) host instead a (dynamic) DNS Seed List:

```
const client = new MongoClient();

const db = await client.connect({
  db: '<your db or collection with work with>',
  tls: true,
  servers: [
    {
      host: '<correct host - the way to get the host - see bellow>',
      port: 27017,
    },
  ],
  credential: {
    username: '<your username>',
    password: '<your password>',
    mechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
  },
});
```

How to get the correct host:

- Open your Cluster in Mongo Atlas
- Select **Connect** button
- Select **Connect to application** option
- Select Driver: **Node.js** and Version: **2.2.12 or later**
- Here you will see a list of host follow **@** character

Answer (score 2):

Wow that was a pain in the ass for me, but I could handle that adding `authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1` and removing `retryWrites=true&w=majority` of the URI. So what you want is:

```js
await client.connect("mongodb+srv://deno:i4vY8AtCEhr6ReqB@sample.7jp1l.mongodb.net/deno?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1");
```

It's been a while I hoped you have solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @nthung.vlvn for the clue. Indeed the host needs to be a primary shard. It fixed the `lookup address information`, but I had another error, that my credentials are incorrect. I had to add db "admin" to credential:

```
credential: {
    username: '<your username>',
    password: '<your password>',
    db: "admin",
    mechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-1',
}
```

That is weird, because I do not have `admin` db in my Atlas. Anyway it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue: I'm using Version `mongo@v0.32.0`

Mongo module wraps Rust Mongo Package under the hood. So to solve this issue. It uses plugins systems, that's why you need `--unstable` flag when running code.

It also needs `--allow-read`, `--allow-write` and `-allow-plugin` permission.

final command would be: `deno run --unstable --allow-read --allow-write --allow-plugin your_app.ts`